# Where should I ask engeneering/manufacturing questions?

Tags: discussion

I am wondering how an  [Archimedean screw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_screw) could be made. Especially, I would be interested how ancient civilizations would do it, say early Greek or Romans.

Physics Stack Exchange does not look like the place to ask this, but for all SE it looks like the least mismatch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm supposing that some features of your question are on topic at [History of Math and Science](http://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Others might be on topic at [Engineering](http://engineering.stackexchange.com).

For the most part it would be off topic on Physics unless it was placed in a very specific experimental context, and frankly I don't see it: pumps are a CoTS thing.

There is, of course, no guarantee that every question will find a place on the network.

Comment: Thank you, somehow I didn't find these.